# Htaccess file keeps appearing | How do I make it stop?

Tags: .htaccess

My host provider uses a LAMP stack...Whenever i log in via an online ftp site...I keep seeing this file

```
.htaccess
```

It is empty.

Do I need it?  What is it for?

I just deleted it b.c. it was empty...I have a feeling it will come back.  How do I keep it from coming back?

Comment: It is a configuration file on a per-directory basis - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess

Answer (score 1):

That file is used by some web servers to protect webpages.

It should show up in your web servers manual page.

Alternatively, google for it. The first nine (9 out of 10) hits on the search term `.htaccess` all give that that information.  It is almost impossible to miss.